# How to get value of draggable element in jQuery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

I am using the jQuery to implement drag and drop. I want to get the value of the draggable control.

```
Draggable Control:
------------------

<li>@Html.Label(temp.Label, new { id = "droppable", style = "color:black; width:auto", value = temp.Key })</li>

Function to show draggable control value:
-----------------------------------------

     function initDroppable($elements) 
     {
            $elements.droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var tempid = ui.draggable;
                    var value = tempid.attr("value");
                    alert(value);
                }
            });
      }
```

Tried above code but the output is "undefined". I have tried various which doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding on to @Stuart, are we looking for `input` or `label`? Like this:

```
var tempid = $(ui.draggable).find("input");
var value = tempid.val();
```

I suspect the dragged item is something like:

```
<li>
  <label id="droppable" style="color:black; width:auto" value="1">Temp</label>
</li>
```

It would be helpful if you showed us e resulting HTML.

Also, why not use `data` attribute?

```
<li>
  <label id="droppable" style="color:black; width:auto" data-temp-key="1">Temp</label>
</li>
```

With:

```
var value = ui.draggable.data("temp-key");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
var tempid = ui.draggable;
```

to:

```
var tempid = $(ui.draggable);
```

and then access the value via the `attr` method:

```
var value = tempid.attr("value");
```

Comment: No luck @stuart, still it shows value as "undefined"

Comment: Did you try `var tempid = ui.draggable.value;`? I suspect that we're missing something from the overall example. Is the element being dragged a `input` or is the `input` wrapped in a `li`?

Comment: Its wrapped in Unordered List

<ul id="source">

        <li>@Html.Label(temp.Label, new { id = "droppable", style = "color:black; width:auto", value = temp.Key })</li>

    </ul>

Comment: @Chaitanya please see the answer I posted. Would also ask that you add `console.log(ui.draggable)` to your code and provide the details from your console or an example of the resulting HTML.